# Codeigniter infinite scroll weird results

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, infinite-scroll

I tried to implement an infinite scroller in my project. I first tried it on a new project and it worked fine, but when I tried to implement it in my other project, I got strange results.

To test it, I've set the limit to 1, so it's supposed to add 1 item everytime now, which it doesn't. It always doubles the amount of items and gives a strange order. So I added an echo with the count/offset of the items and I got something like this. (the numbers are the echo offsets and each line is a scroll and is supposed to add only 1 item):

First: 1 (= 1 item)

Second: 1 - 2 - 2 (= 3 items)

Third: 1 - 2 - 4 - 4 - 2 - 4 - 4 (= 7 items)

Fourth: 1 - 2 - 4 - 8 - 8 - 4 - 8 - 8 - 2 - 4 - 8 - 8 - 4 - 8 - 8 (= 15 items)

And so on... Also, the same numbers are always the same items. So I got a lot of double items. I also tried did an alert(count($items)); before the foreach wich only gave 1 as a result.

This is the code of the Ajax:

```
var reachedEnd = false;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {

        setTimeout(function() {
            lastPostFunc();
        }, 1000);
    }
});

function lastPostFunc() {
    var trs = $('.sresult-row'); 
    var count = trs.length; //offset

    if (reachedEnd == false) {
        alert("test"); //I only get 1 alert after each scroll 
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost/ci/index.php/search/ajax_searchJob/" + count,
                async: false,
                dataType: "html",
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data != "End")
                        $('.result-bd').append(data);
                    else
                        reachedEnd = true;
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Just a small part of my controller:

```
public function ajax_searchJob($offset = null) {
    if ($this->job_model->searchJobUnique($where, 1, $offset)) {
        $jobs = $this->job_model->searchJobUnique($where, 1, $offset);
        echo $offset; //This gives the result I've said before 
        ...
        $this->load->view("default/search-job-result-ajax", $data);
    } else {
        echo 'End';
    }
}
```

My model in case anyone wants to see it:

```
public function searchJobUnique($where, $limit = 1, $offset = 0)
{
      $sql = "SELECT *,job.id as id, job.country as country, job.province as province, job.city as city,
            job.employment_length as employment_length, job.employment_type employment_type,
            u.username as company_name, job.company_id as company_id, u.description as description,
            job.is_visa_assistance, job.is_visa_assistance,
            ms.employment_type as msjob_employment_type,
            ms.employment_length as msjob_employment_length,
            ms.is_visa_assistance as msjob_is_visa_assistance,
            ms.is_housing_assistance as msjob_is_housing_assistance,
            ms.language_level as msjob_language_level,
            ms.industry_position as msjob_industry_position
                      FROM job
                      LEFT JOIN user as u on job.company_id=u.uid
                      LEFT JOIN job_industry_position as jip on job.id=jip.job_id
                      LEFT JOIN match_score as ms on job.id=ms.job_id".$where."  ORDER BY job.post_date DESC 
                      limit " . $limit . " offset " . $offset;
      $r = $this->db->query($sql);

      if ($r->num_rows > 0) {
        return $r->result_array();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
  }
```

I really want to solve this problem. I used the same code that I used in my testproject where it works perfectly.

Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your JS, I take that `$('.result-bd')` is the place holder for your `$('.sresult-row')`, the possibility that your not being able to get the row count precisely is because the items appended are yet to be loaded on the DOM, in result, your ajax req submtting incorrect values to ur controller, I would suggest that you make sure that the `$('.sresult-row')` are loaded before proceeding in assigning any value to your `count`, ie in your code you could try:

```
var reachedEnd = false;
var count = 1; //give your offset a default value first
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {

            $.when(lastPostFunc()).then(function(){ //make sure that the result items gets appended
               var trs = $('.sresult-row'); //assigning new instances of sr-row everytime 
               setTimeout(function() { //provide a short lag time just to make sure that .result-row is already existing in the dom 
                  count = parseInt(trs.length, 10); //assigns a new value for your offset
               }, 500);
            });

    }
});

function lastPostFunc() {
    if (reachedEnd == false) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost/ci/index.php/search/ajax_searchJob/" + count,
                async: false,
                dataType: "html",
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data != "End")
                        $('.result-bd').append(data);
                    else
                        reachedEnd = true;
                }
            });
    }
}
```

haven't tried if this works, hope it helps, cheers!